# How do I make Selenium drag and drop operations faster?

Tags: python, performance, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I am new to Selenium, which I am using with Python. I want it to perform some drag and drop actions. I have been through a tutorial. Here:

[Drag and drop action tutorial](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/drag-and-drop-in-selenium-python/)

The code appears to work perfectly so this is not a bug fix.

The trouble is the operation occurs slowly. It takes about a second or so to complete. This will mean I will need to wait a very long time for it to complete many drag and drop operations.

I have tried a Google search and have found no tutorials for speeding up this operation. There is no part of the tutorial code I can find which sends any parameters to a speed control.

What I want is for it to perform the operation instantaneously, so I don't need to wait. I don't need or want to watch it happen.

Is there a way to speed up the drag and drop action so it occurs immediately, or at least faster? Is there a different Selenium function I could use which will perform the operation immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Id locator instead of Xpath, please find the reference code below.

WebElement draglocator = driver.findElement(By.id("Bhairu123"));

```
    action.dragAndDropBy(draglocator,Drag,Drop.build().perform();
```

Comment: No. This is just how to find the element faster. The action will still occur at the same speed. I want the actual drag and drop operation itself to be faster. I think maybe the answer is to use moveto instead?